# ODI Agent - Context error

Tags: agent, oracle-data-integrator

I'm new to ODI and I'm making some tutorials,
I've created a physical and a logical agent and after editing the odiparams.bat and setting the correct driver and URL.

When I try to start the agent I get the following error:

[image]

The port number is correct and everything seems fine. Howerver it doesn't work
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the space between "-NAME=" and "MyAgent" and it will work.